# Build agent ID via TFS sdk

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS2018 api and I need to get the build agent id for different team projects. How can I get the list of agent queue ids using the TFS sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [well-documented](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/queues/overview).

`GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=3.0-preview.1`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes but is there a build in way using the SDK or do I have to construct the url?

Comment: @doorman Doesn't look like it. The C# object model is a convenience wrapper around the REST API; not everything in the REST API is available.

Comment: Hi Daniel, is it possible to use the BuildHttpClient to call the rest api url?